# Sort an array of hashes by hash's first element with key as a string

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I have the following array/hash:

```
[{"XYZ140717"=>
   {:unit=>10.25,
    :perc=>0.0,
    :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}},
 {"ABC140719"=>
   {:unit=>8.71,
    :perc=>0.0,
    :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}},
 {"MNO140718"=>
   {:unit=>8.55,
    :perc=>0.0,
    :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}}]
```

And I want to sort it so the first will be ABC140719, followed by MNO XYZ.
I could not figure a way of doing it.

Comment: Does each hash really have only one key? If so, you may be better off designing your data structures differently. Further, your example is not valid Ruby (dates cannot be expressed that way).

Comment: Yes, only one. That is how I receive the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the difficulty is that your data structure doesn’t really make sense. Instead let’s make the “key” be simply an element of each hash (change `:key` to whatever semantically makes sense):

```
items = [...] # your data from question
items = items.map do |hash|
  key, values = hash.first
  { key: key }.merge(values)
end
#=> [{:key=>"XYZ140717", :unit=>10.25, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"},
#    {:key=>"ABC140719", :unit=>8.71, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"},
#    {:key=>"MNO140718", :unit=>8.55, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"}]
```

Now it becomes rather simple to use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
items.sort_by { |item| item[:key] }
#=> [{:key=>"ABC140719", :unit=>8.71, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"},
#    {:key=>"MNO140718", :unit=>8.55, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"},
#    {:key=>"XYZ140717", :unit=>10.25, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>"2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000"}]
```

If you insist on keeping your current data structure, you can of course do the following:

```
items.sort_by { |hash| hash.keys.first }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorting your array is quite easy, as you can leverage on the fact that if `sort_by` receives a block which returns an array, it compares the first element in the returning array first, and then uses the rest as tie-breakers. Turning each of your hashes to an array will do the trick:

```
items.sort_by(&:to_a)
# => [{"ABC140719"=>{:unit=>8.71, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}},
#     {"MNO140718"=>{:unit=>8.55, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}}, 
#     {"XYZ140717"=>{:unit=>10.25, :perc=>0.0, :exp=>2014-07-19 00:00:00 +1000}}]
```